# Laravel: Check if the field was filled in the route, using Trait and Scope

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant

I have an api that I am implementing multi-tenant based on an additional column in the tables.

For this I created a trait that implements a
static::addGlobalScope() and static::creating().

I have a user_idXtenant_id table. In this table I store the accesses that the user has.

My Route looks like this:

```
Route::get('{tenant_id}/products', function ($tenant_id) {
        return App\Products::where(['tenant_id' => $tenant_id])->get();
    })->middleware('role_or_permission:admin|seller|get-products');

Route::get('products', function () {
        return App\Products::get();
    })->middleware('role_or_permission:admin|seller|get-products');
```

The idea is that in the first route it is verified if the user has access to tenant_id and if he has access, return only the products of that tenant_id (here Polices can be useful and solve the problem).

The second route, on the other hand, must return all products of all tenant_id that the user has access to. For this, I use static :: addGlobalScope() to set the tenants that the user has access to in this way:

```
$builder->whereIn('tenant_id', $tenants);
```

The question is how to check in GlobalScope if tenant_id was filled in the model. So, if it is present, I only check the permission and if it is not present I include the tenant_id that the user has access to.

I hope I have been able to adequately exemplify the problem.

Any help is most welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: I think you are not fully utilizing Laravel's feature using this method? I suggest reading on Controllers, Requests, and Policy, which should be plenty to accomplish access restriction and validation.

Comment: Daniel thanks for the quick response.
I'm new to Laravel and I didn't know the Polices very well. I believe that the Polices can solve part of the problem. But, I think the question was missing information. Include them in the question. Do you have any suggestions on how to resolve the second route?

Comment: You should create a [Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers) with a method for that route. Dependency Inject a custom [Request](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests), which will validate the existence of the `tenant_id`. Apply a policy to guard the resource, i.e. check if the user has the required permissions. If the script passes all of these, that means the user can view the resource and it exists. Then return the query results e.g. in a JSON response.

Comment: You may guard the resources using middleware like you are currently doing, or move to Policy if there will be more complex logic deciding if the user can access the resource.

Comment: I am also against using Eloquent's Global Scope in this scenario, because the docs suggest the operation is applied to each model query. However, in your case, you wanted to filter responses for different users. So they are not the same. Models do not belong to users. It's best to completely skim/read through Laravel docs to see what it offers.

Comment: Daniel thanks for reply. I read the laravel documentation on the Policies and Gates part. I understood the need and the applications. I ended up solving only in middleware.
Doing the necessary checks and allowing access if you have permission.
Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Nice. If you feel that this question no longer needs an answer, you should delete it as this current page would not likely help another user.